# Python Connect to Dockerized Postgres Database

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have the following `docker-compose.yaml file`:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

I try to connect with Python like this:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import Error

# Connect to an existing database
connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                              password="postgres",
                              host="127.0.0.1",
                              port="5432",
                              database="postgres_db")
```

I also can not connect with DB Navigator: `FATAL: Password-Authentication for user >>postgres<< failed`

the `pg_hba.conf` values are set to "trust" (by default), which I saw as potential error from other users here.

Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: *Which* `pg_hba.conf` values are set to `trust`? Can you show us the relevant configuration? Note also that `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` is only relevant when you're starting from scratch; if you previously used the `db` volume with another password, it will not be updated.

Comment: Your `docker-compose.yaml` file and your Python code work fine for me with no modifications. Ensure you're starting from a clean slate (`docker-compose down -v` to remove volumes) and test again. Ensure you don't already have another Postgres instance listening on port 5432.

Comment: thank you very much. Turned out i had an old database running on my system. I changed the port and everything works now